# How to check if user logged in days consecutively

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**The Task**

To find out if a user has logged in 5 days in a row.

**Sample Table**

```
+----+---------+---------------------+
| id | user_id |   date_logged_in    |
+----+---------+---------------------+
|  1 |      29 | 2019-10-25 22:00:16 |
|  2 |      29 | 2019-10-26 22:00:16 |
|  3 |      29 | 2019-10-27 22:00:16 |
|  4 |      29 | 2019-10-28 22:00:16 |
|  5 |      29 | 2019-10-29 22:00:16 |
+----+---------+---------------------+
```

So in this case, the query would return **TRUE** because user #29 has logged in 5 days in a row.

Thanks for any help. This is way above my pay grade!

Comment: What are you looking for? The MySQL query? PHP code? What have you tried before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL 8+, you can use window functions:

```
select distinct user
from (select user, date(date_logged_in) as dli,
             lead(date(date_logged_in), 4) over (partition by user order by date(date_logged_in)) as next_dli_4
      from t
      group by user, date(date_logged_in)
     ) ud
where next_dli_4 = dli + interval 4 day;
```

In older versions, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select distinct user
from (select t.*,
             (select date(date_logged_in)
              from t t2
              where t2.user = t.user and
                    date(t2.date_logged_in) > t.date_logged_in
              group by date(date_logged_in)
              offset 4 limit 1
             ) as next_dli_4
      from t
     ) t
where next_dli_4 = date(date_logged_in) + interval 4 day;
```

EDIT:

Another fun alternative uses `join`:

```
select t.user, date(t4.date_logged_in)
from t join
     t t4
     on t4.user = t.user and
        date(t4.date_logged_in) >= date(t.date_logged_in) and
        date(t4.date_logged_in) <= date(t.date_logged_in) + interval 4
group by t.user, date(t.date_logged_in)
having count(distinct date(t4.date_logged_in)) = 5;
```

This is doing an interval join matching on any days up to four days after.  The outer aggregation then counts the distinct days.

Comment: I apologize if I confused anyone, I was looking for the SQL. Based on the above answer, I was able work out an answer using some of the code. It sure isnt an easy query as one would think, huh.